# create tags only if values are found in the XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi  need to create tags only if values are found in the XML

I am converting XML to XML using XSL
my problem is to create tags only if values are found  in the input XML .
I referred many things and created XSL but  not working could you please help me .
Thanks!

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href= "D:\Vignesh\Task\RFC\FIS107_24Feb1\MyChanges\XSL SHEET\ThirdIP-HostIP.xsl"?>
<rsm:Waybill     xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:standard:CoreComponentsTechnicalSpecificati    on:2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:8"
xmlns:rsm="iata:waybill:1" xmlns:ram="iata:datamodel:3">
<rsm:MessageHeaderDocument>
<ram:ID>01463898855</ram:ID> 
<rsm:MessageHeaderDocument>
</rsm:Waybill>
```

My  XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:standard:CoreComponentsTechnicalSpecification:2"             xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:8"
         xmlns:rsm="iata:waybill:1"           xmlns:ram="iata:datamodel:3">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" ></xsl:output>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:if test="rsm:Waybill/rsm:MessageHeaderDocument/ram:ID"> 
        <xsl:text><![CDATA[<ROUTING>]]></xsl:text>
        <xsl:text><![CDATA[<ORIGIN>]]></xsl:text>
        <xsl:text><![CDATA[ <STATION> ]]></xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/rsm:Waybill/rsm:MasterConsignment/ram:OriginLocation/ram:ID"/>
        <xsl:text><![CDATA[</STATION> ]]></xsl:text>
        <xsl:text><![CDATA[</ORIGIN>]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output will be like 
if value is in ram:ID then:

```
<ROUTING>
    <ORIGIN>
    <STATION>
        01463898855
    <STATION>
    </ORIGIN>
</ROUTING>
```

iF NOT THEN : no tags should be created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your the line

`<xsl:if test="rsm:Waybill/rsm:MessageHeaderDocument/ram:ID">`

into

```
<xsl:if test="rsm:Waybill/rsm:MessageHeaderDocument/ram:ID and rsm:Waybill/rsm:MessageHeaderDocument/ram:ID != ''">
```

that should also test if there is a value for ram:ID

Comment: You are not addressing at all the main, worst problem here -- see the answer by @Michael-Kay.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm sorry i missed that everything is in Text and CDATA i just focused on the condition here @Vignesh you should really have a look at Mr. Kay's answer here. My answer fixes the condition but not the other obvious problems with your XML Output.

Comment: With the node set comparison, the existencial test is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

But if you fix that problem, your output won't be what you want. It will be

```
&lt;ROUTING&gt;
    &lt;ORIGIN&gt;
    &lt;STATION&gt;
        01463898855
    &lt;/STATION&gt;
    &lt;/ORIGIN&gt;
&lt;/ROUTING&gt;
```

You need a deeper understanding of what XSLT is all about. Or if you just want to fix it without gaining a deeper understanding, rewrite it as

```
<xsl:if test="rsm:Waybill/rsm:MessageHeaderDocument/ram:ID != ''"> 
  <ROUTING>
    <ORIGIN>
      <STATION>
        <xsl:value-of select="/rsm:Waybill/rsm:MasterConsignment/ram:OriginLocation/ram:ID"/>
      </STATION>
    </ORIGIN>
  </ROUTING>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:if test="string(rsm:Waybill/rsm:MessageHeaderDocument/ram:ID)">
     do your strange stuff..
</xsl:if>
```

It would be `true` if a string-value of `ram:ID` isn't a zero-length string.

Comment: +1 This is also correct. And if you go that way , you could also use `normalize-space()` function.

Answer (score 0):

**There are a number of problems**:

1. You are not creating 2-dimensional markup -- just a 1-dimensional string.
2. In XSLT conditional instructions are best avoided, if possible.

**One possible solution to both problems:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="rsm:MessageHeaderDocument[ram:ID]">
    <ROUTING>
        <ORIGIN>
            <STATION>
                <xsl:value-of select=
                "/*/rsm:MasterConsignment/ram:OriginLocation/ram:ID"/>
            </STATION>
        </ORIGIN>
    </ROUTING>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The elements (literal result elements) are created really as elements, not as string.
2. Using a separate `<xsl:template>` with pattern matching avoids the need of conditional xslt instructions inside the body of a template.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this as a comment, but because i do not have enough reputation, i cannot add comment to the voted answer.

Please note that the voted answer has a duplicate test condition. 
Edit: this was mentioned as a comment and also in another answer.

```
<xsl:if test="rsm:Waybill/rsm:MessageHeaderDocument/ram:ID and rsm:Waybill/rsm:MessageHeaderDocument/ram:ID != ''">
```

The solution is ,

```
<xsl:if test="rsm:Waybill/rsm:MessageHeaderDocument/ram:ID != ''">
```

I have tested this.

`<xsl:if test="someelement!=''">` will check **both** if the `<someelement>` is present , as well as the element has a value.

`<xsl:if test="someelement">` will check **only** if the `<someelement>` is present

Also there is

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(someelement)=0">
```

This checks if the value is empty, hence it returns true if `somelement` is not present, as well as when it is present, but have an empty value.